# How to use Taxonomy to tag/categories content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I installed and enabled the Taxonomy module, created an *Event* content type, and a "International Competition" node of that type. I want to apply the tags *senior*, *male*, and *annual* to this event.

I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried reading the documentation for the Taxonomy module but can't figure out where in the CMS I am supposed to associate tags to a node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The steps to follow to be able to use a vocabulary with nodes of a content type are two:

- Create the vocabulary, if it doesn't exist, on admin/structure/taxonomy.

  [image: screenshot]
- Associate the vocabulary with the content type on; for example, for the *Article* content type, the page is admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields.

  - Add a new field, using "Term reference" as field type.

  [image: screenshot]

  - Click the "Save" button, and select the vocabulary that is used for the taxonomy terms that will be added.

  [image: screenshot]

  - Change the settings in the page that appears after you click on the "Save field settings" button.

This is different from Drupal 6, where the form to create (or edit) a vocabulary also allowed to select which content type should use that vocabulary. In Drupal 7 is changed, as a vocabulary can be associated to other entities, such as users (see admin/config/people/accounts/fields) and vocabularies (see admin/structure/taxonomy/forums/fields for the "Forums" vocabulary).

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]